# Mac Calendar App not Syncing Google Calendar

Tags: macos, mac, calendar, ical, google-calendar

I have removed the account from my computer. I have cleared the Calendar cache multiple times. I have refreshed my Calendar. I have made sure that calendar syncing is active on the Google side of things. I feel like I have tried everything, but I still cannot get my Google Calendar to show up on the Mac Calendar app. Also, no I did not accidentally hit the arrow beside the word "Google" to hide the calendar. I do not know what else to try to get this resolved.

[image]

Comment: Having this too on an older Mac. Just updated to macOS 11.2.1 and still broke

Comment: looks like this is widespread https://twitter.com/scott4pendleton/status/1364094339375226885 and https://downdetector.com/status/google-calendar/

Comment: Even the MFA push notifications to the Gmail app are slow. This seems like a Google issue rather than Apple.